# Cannot write comment to my own "dark" post via Graph API - only receive OauthException 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I write some *dark post* on my fanpage. (Dark post is a post, that is not published). Then I can get the post object using the graph api.

But if I try to write a comment via the graph api (Post to the post_id/comments resource) to this special kind of posts, facebook responds with a OAuthException 100.

```
{"error": {
    "message": "(#100) Error finding the requested story", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
    }
 }
```

On normal posts this is working fine.

Is there some special trick to write comments to dark posts via the API or is this not possible?

BTW: same problem on hidden and spam posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot like or comment on a story that is not published yet.

Comment: So this seems to be a missing feature in the API, because I can comment if I use the Facebook Page?

Comment: With a page access token it IS possible to comment to any kind of post on that page the token belongs to (dark, spam, hidden and normal) even replying is possible.